# How to read a non-UTF8 encoded csv file?

Tags: csv, character-encoding, rust, windows-1252

With the [csv](https://docs.rs/crate/csv/1.0.5) crate and the latest Rust version 1.31.0, I would want to read CSV files with ANSI (Windows 1252) encoding, as easily as in UTF-8.

Things I have tried (with no luck), after reading the whole file in a `Vec<u8>`:

- [`CString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html)
- [`OsString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html)

Indeed, in my company, we have a lot of CSV files, ANSI encoded.

Also, I would want, if possible, not to load the entire file in a `Vec<u8>` but a reading line by line (`CRLF` ending), as many of the files are big (50 Mb or more…).

In the file *Cargo.toml*, I have this dependency:

```
[dependencies]
csv = "1"
```

*test.csv* consist of the following content saved as Windows-1252 encoding:

```
Café;au;lait
Café;au;lait
```

The code in *main.rs* file:

```
extern crate csv;

use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::path::Path;
use std::process;

fn example() -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    let file_name = r"test.csv";
    let file_handle = File::open(Path::new(file_name))?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file_handle);

    let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
        .delimiter(b';')
        .from_reader(reader);

    // println!("ANSI");
    // for result in rdr.byte_records() {
    //    let record = result?;
    //    println!("{:?}", record);
    // }

    println!("UTF-8");
    for result in rdr.records() {
        let record = result?;
        println!("{:?}", record);
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(err) = example() {
        println!("error running example: {}", err);
        process::exit(1);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
UTF-8
error running example: CSV parse error: record 0 (line 1, field: 0, byte: 0): invalid utf-8: invalid UTF-8 in field 0 near byte index 3
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\test-csv.exe` (exit code: 1)
```

When using `rdr.byte_records()` (uncommenting the relevant part of code), the output is:

```
ANSI
ByteRecord(["Caf\\xe9", "au", "lait"])
```

Comment: @LinkerStorm Could you please explain why your last code snippet is insufficient to solve your problem? Byte records give you raw access to the bytes in a somewhat encoding asgnostic way. (The only requirement is that the encoding be ASCII compatible, which I believe Windows-1252 is.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I suspect this question is under specified. In particular, it's not clear why your use of the [`ByteRecord`](https://docs.rs/csv/1.0.5/csv/struct.ByteRecord.html) API is insufficient. In the csv crate, byte records specifically exists for exactly cases like this, where your CSV data isn't strictly UTF-8, but is in an alternative encoding such as Windows-1252 that is ASCII compatible. (An ASCII compatible encoding is an encoding in which ASCII is a subset. Windows-1252 and UTF-8 are both ASCII compatible. UTF-16 is not.) Your code sample above shows that you're using byte records, but doesn't explain why this is insufficient.

With that said, if your goal is to get your data into Rust's string data type (`String`/`&str`), then your *only option* is to transcode the contents of your CSV data from Windows-1252 to UTF-8. This is necessary because Rust's string data type uses UTF-8 for its in-memory representation. You cannot have a Rust `String`/`&str` that is Windows-1252 encoded because Windows-1252 is not a subset of UTF-8.

Other comments have recommended the use of the `encoding` crate. However, I would instead recommend the use of [`encoding_rs`](https://docs.rs/encoding_rs/0.8.13/encoding_rs/), if your use case aligns with the same use cases solved by the [Encoding Standard](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/), which is specifically geared towards the web. Fortunately, I believe such an alignment exists.

In order to satisfy your criteria for reading CSV data in a streaming fashion without first loading the entire contents into memory, you need to use a wrapper around the `encoding_rs` crate that implements streaming decoding for you. The [`encoding_rs_io`](https://docs.rs/encoding_rs_io/0.1.3/encoding_rs_io/) crate provides this for you. (It's used inside of [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) to do fast streaming decoding before searching UTF-8.)

Here is an example program that puts all of the above together, using Rust 2018:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::process;

use encoding_rs::WINDOWS_1252;
use encoding_rs_io::DecodeReaderBytesBuilder;

fn main() {
    if let Err(err) = try_main() {
        eprintln!("{}", err);
        process::exit(1);
    }
}

fn try_main() -> csv::Result<()> {
    let file = File::open("test.csv")?;
    let transcoded = DecodeReaderBytesBuilder::new()
        .encoding(Some(WINDOWS_1252))
        .build(file);
    let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
        .delimiter(b';')
        .from_reader(transcoded);
    for result in rdr.records() {
        let r = result?;
        println!("{:?}", r);
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

with the `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "so53826986"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
csv = "1"
encoding_rs = "0.8.13"
encoding_rs_io = "0.1.3"
```

And the output:

```
$ cargo run --release
   Compiling so53826986 v0.1.0 (/tmp/so53826986)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.63s
     Running `target/release/so53826986`
StringRecord(["Café", "au", "lait"])
```

In particular, if you swap out `rdr.records()` for `rdr.byte_records()`, then we can see more clearly what happened:

```
$ cargo run --release
   Compiling so53826986 v0.1.0 (/tmp/so53826986)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.61s
     Running `target/release/so53826986`
ByteRecord(["Caf\\xc3\\xa9", "au", "lait"])
```

Namely, your input contained `Caf\xE9`, but the byte record now contains `Caf\xC3\xA9`. This is a result of translating the Windows-1252 codepoint value of `233` (encoded as its literal byte, `\xE9`) to `U+00E9 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE`, which is UTF-8 encoded as `\xC3\xA9`.

Comment: Thanks @BurnSushi5, you've got the point : my goal is to get the data in Rust string datatype.
And you've answered my question, many thanks !

Comment: It's amazing how some people make such an out-sized contribution. This would be the umpteenth time BurntSushi saved me from drowning in Rust. Thanks Andrew! :)